# How to upload an attachment in Ivanti service request using REST API

Tags: c#, rest, post, postman

I'm trying to upload an attachment to a Ivanti service request from postman. This is the documentation I followed

https://help.ivanti.com/ht/help/en_US/ISM/2020/admin/Content/Configure/API/Upload-Attachments.htm

can somebody help how to send the request body and how the file is attached while sending the request.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to set up the Authorization (e.g. with an API key) and then upload the file.

In Postman you can do that by selecting "form-data" in the body section and switching to "file" as the Key and attaching your file as the value.

[Screenshot Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kaPG.png)